# I cloned a repository into my project. Should I commit that repo in my project repo?

Tags: git, github, version-control

There was a package (which was not available by Composer and other package managers) that I need to use it in my project.

So I cloned it into vendor directory.
Now I want to push my project files to another git repository.

What should I do with that package? Add its folder to .gitignore?

Answer (score 1):

You can add it as a `submodule`.

Your repository would hold:

- an URL to the source repo of the package
- the SHA1 of the commit that is the version you need.

For example:

```
$ git submodule add http://link/to/reference/repo vendor
```

You might need to move your directory `vendor` first.

If you modify something in `vendor` and commit these changes, your top repo will mark it as a change: the commit of `vendor` that is in use has changed. That way you track which version of `vendor` was needed for each commit in your top repo.

Note: `submodules` are a bit special upon checking out. A checkout in your top repo updates which SHA1 of `vendor` is valid, but does not update the working files themselves. To do that, you need to `git submodule update` in the top level, just after checking out.

Comment: But people say its not recommended: https://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/why-your-company-shouldnt-use-git-submodules/

Comment: It depends on the situation. It is complex, but it solves complex situations. I like it, but I have to admit it took a while to get used to it.

Comment: If you don't think you'll get updates from the vendor too often, or that you'll make your own development in the package, which you'd like to use in other projects, then you might as well add the vendor directory as part of the top repository.